# Grouping a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert string l1 into a list of dictionaries like shown in the example_dict.

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

But the code is returning no value, can you help?

```
  import re

   l1="146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST 
   /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 
   [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE/virtual/solutions/target/web+services 
   HTTP/2.0" 203 26554\n"
 
    def logs():
    with open("logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
 
        pattern= r'(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+) - (?P<user_name>[\w-]+) \[(? 
        P<time>[^\]]+)\] "(? 
       P<request>[^"]+)"'
        logs1=[]
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
            print(item.groupdict())
            logs1.append(item) 
    return(logs1) 
   len(logs())'''
```

Comment: Your `l1` string literal is not well-formed. Please fix.

Comment: Btw, it feels all you need is `logs1 = [x.groupdict() for x in re.finditer(pattern, logdata)]`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Zz1zE2).

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get [`Match.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) for each match data object you return with [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```py
logs1 = [x.groupdict() for x in re.finditer(pattern, logdata)]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Zz1zE2):

```py
import re
logdata="""146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554\n"""
pattern= r'(?P<host>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+) - (?P<user_name>[\w-]+) \[(?P<time>[^\]]+)\] "(?P<request>[^"]+)"'
logs1 = [x.groupdict() for x in re.finditer(pattern, logdata)]
print(logs1) 
# => [
#        {'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'},
#        {'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}
#    ]
```